# using Collections.binarySearch to remove duplicates from a pre-populated ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, duplicates

For an assignment, I have been given the task of reading in a pre-populated file as an ArrayList, sorting it, and removing all duplicates. I have been tasked to doing this with the binarySearch API.  He's being rather specific. I have never done this before, and I'm not sure what I need to do to get Collections.binarySearch to work. The instructor gave me a start, but I know I am doing the parameters of Collections.binarySearch incorrectly, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the correct way to do this.  If anyone can help out, it would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have so far.  If it matters at all, I can post the integers from set1.txt

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    collections program = new Collections();
    program.readFile();
}//main

public void readFile() {
    File f = new File("set1.txt");
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            int x = in.nextInt();
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(x,0);
            if (index == 1)
                list.add(x);
        }//while
        Collections.sort(list);

        in.close();
    }//try
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//catch
}//readFile
```

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc for `Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-)? There are some preconditions that you need to fulfill that I don't think you're fulfilling, as well as information on the proper parameters to use.

Comment: Have you considered just using some kind of `Set`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It seems that the problem description requires this particular use, but I agree that a `Set` would be the optimal solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with Set. the binarySearch was not necessarily a full on requirement, just something repeatedly suggested.  If something is more effective, I'm sure it would be fine. I'm just stuck, having never used collections.binarySearch or Sets.

Comment: Oh, I see. My mistake. The [javadoc for `Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is a good place to start. You'll find a description of what one is there.

Comment: Binary search requires a sorted array, and it is clear that your file is not sorted. To make it work you should keep the list sorted before each time you do binary search, that is the loop invariance.

Comment: Question for you to think about. In a properly sorted array, where will duplicate values be, relative to each other? Given that, do you need binarySearch to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sorted the list, duplicate elements (if any) will be next to one another, so you can simply iterate over the list removing any duplicate elements, no searching required.  (We iterate backwards to avoid the awkwardness of deciding whether to increment the loop counter after removing an element.)

```
Collections.sort(list);
for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
    if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1)))
        list.remove(i);
```

---

But a more convenient way to ensure uniqueness is to create a `Set` holding the contents of your list, then create a new list from the set.  The new list will contain the unique elements of the input list in the set's iteration order, so we can sort at the same time by using a `TreeSet`.  (Using a `HashSet` to create the list, then calling `Collections.sort(list)` may or may not be faster, and the above solution may be faster still -- if it matters to you, profile to ensure it's a problem, then benchmark.)

```
list = new ArrayList<>(new TreeSet<>(list));
```

If reusing the input list is important (either as an arbitrary homework requirement or to minimize memory use/churn), you can do something like

```
Set<T> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the new Java is out, I might as well post this to help "future seekers".

```
ArrayList<String> newList = oldList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```